# NSUndoManager not working. Aaron Hillegass chapter 9

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have been working through cocoa programming for Mac OS X by Aaron Hillegass.  I have become stuck on chapter 9.  I have added the 2 methods necessary to allow the undo and redo functions to be called.  However, when I build and run the application, according to the book, the methods should be automatically called, yet they are not.  They are spelt correctly as you can see below...

**2 additional methods in MyDocument.m**

```
- (void)insertObject:(Person *)p inEmployeesAtIndex:(int)index
{
    NSLog(@"Adding %@ to %@", p, employees);
        //Add the inverse of this operation to the undo stack
    NSUndoManager *undo = [self undoManager];
    [[undo prepareWithInvocationTarget:self]removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:index];
    if (![undo isUndoing]){
        [undo setActionName:@"Insert Person"];
    }
        //Add teh person to the array
    [employees insertObject:p atIndex:index];
}

- (void)removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:(int)index
{
    Person *p = [employees objectAtIndex:index];
    NSLog(@"Removing %@ to %@", p, employees);
        //Add the inverse of this operation to the undo stack
    NSUndoManager *undo = [self undoManager];
    [[undo prepareWithInvocationTarget:self]insertObject:p inEmployeesAtIndex:index];
    if (![undo isUndoing]){
        [undo setActionName:@"Delete Person"];
    }
    [employees removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

**myDocument.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class Person;

@interface MyDocument : NSDocument
{
    NSMutableArray *employees;
}
- (void)setEmployees:(NSMutableArray *)a;
- (void)removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:(int)index;
- (void)insertObject:(Person *)p inEmployeesAtIndex:(int)index;
@end
```

Any help would be great, thanks :)

Comment: What are you expecting to automatically call them?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented the getter for `employees`. Assuming you intend to use Key-Value Coding to modify the array, either directly or through Bindings, you need to implement both the getter and the setter for this object to be KVC-compliant for this property.

Once you meet the minimum requirements for KVC compliance, then KVC will recognize the property and use its accessors, including any array accessors you implement.

If you look in the Debugger Console, you may find that KVC is already telling you this, in the form of “`<Some object> is not KVC-compliant for <some property>`” exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you're not using KVC to access this property, then you need to make sure you're using the array accessors to access it.

If, when saving, restoring, or applying edits, you talk to the array directly (`[employees setArray:]` or `[employees insertObject:… atIndex…]`/`[employees removeObjectAtIndex:…]`), then the side effects of your accessors don't happen, because you didn't use them. You implemented undo support in your accessors (at least the two whose implementations you showed), and if anything is observing the property via KVO, that is another side effect; both of these things do not happen if you don't use your accessors.

If your `setEmployees:` accessor does not talk to the Undo Manager (you omitted that code in your question, so I can't tell), then that will not add an undo action. The Undo Manager will work fine if you talk to it, but if you don't, then it can't.

You must send yourself `insertObject:inEmployeesAtIndex:` and `removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:` messages in order for the changes to be recorded in the undo manager, if those are the only places you're talking to the undo manager. If you want to make wholesale replacement (`setEmployees:`) undoable, then you must also add an undo action to the manager there.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.  My array controller was not bound to the file owner.  After doing this it all magically seems to work! I really hope by the end of this book I will start to understand at least some of it :(  Thanks, anyway